# laravel passport returns unauthenticated

Tags: php, api, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-passport

I'm creating an api that uses Passport to manage authentication. I've set up Passport with [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport).

### The problem

I am unable to login. I keep getting a JSON response saying `unauthenticated`

### Database

In my database I have the following data:

**users**

```
id  name    email           password                                                           timestamps
1   admin   admin@admin.com $2y$10$mUu5KZdQhJ6qeyCeXsr9De0J9e8rgClILbhsGmnPpStwr1rhaa2je            2016-12-09 09:47:39 2016-12-09 09:47:39`
```

`

**oauth_clients**

```
 id, user_id, name, secret, redirect, personal_access_client, password_client, revoked, created_at, updated_at
  1, , Leerplatform app Password Grant Client, f37igMCW3cj6Dv8n4OM8uhBO98Geoag4vgmgptq0, http://localhost, 0, 1, 0, 2016-12-09 10:06:30, 2016-12-09 10:06:30
```

### Http request

I make the following request to `/oauth/token`

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8000/oauth/token
Request Method:POST
Status Code:401 Unauthorized
Remote Address:[::1]:8000
grant_type:password
client_id:1
client_secret:f37igMCW3cj6Dv8n4OM8uhBO98Geoag4vgmgptq0
username:admin@admin.com
password:admin
scope:*
```

### Things I've tried

1. Truncating access token & refresh token table

   - I did this because it used to work and suddenly stopped working
2. Deleting all Laravel sessions
3. Setting expiration dates

   `Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(15));
   Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(30));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I mapped my passport routes in my `RouteServiceProvider` and not in my `AuthServiceProvider`