# Passport laravel returns Unauthenticated always

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I am using laravel/passport for the first time. I did the following steps in my existing code package.

1. composer require laravel/passport
2. php artisan migrate
3. Included piece of code as follows

   ```
   //app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php
   Passport::routes();
   Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(15));
   Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(30));

   //app/User.php
   use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
   use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

   //config/auth.php
   'api' => [
       'driver' => 'passport',
       'provider' => 'users',
   ],
   ```
4. And in route file middleware is `auth:api`. I am getting token on login. But always passport returning *Unauthenticated*

Tried with,

[Passport Package returning "Unauthenticated" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50674552/passport-package-returning-unauthenticated-error)

[laravel passport returns unauthenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41058291/laravel-passport-returns-unauthenticated)

Not yet solved.

Comment: How do you set your Authentication Header?

Comment: Check your `callback` url?

Comment: @MartinHenriksen Authorization : Bearer _token_ . Using postman.

Comment: @PS1212 I am not using callback uri.

Comment: Also tried a fresh installation.

Comment: Just a thing i once failed with, if in postman authorization tab was set to something incorrect it could overwrite your authorization header. Just a shot in the dark.

Comment: @NoName some solution to this problem, which also has me crazy